# set parent domain for cookie using Owin + OpenID

Tags: asp.net, cookies, openid, owin, katana

I use Owin+OpenId to Sign In for two web sites site1.azurewebsites.net and site2.azurewebsites.net, I want to share authentication cookie between them by setting CookieName = ".azurewebsite.net", however I can't find any related samples. I tried to set CookieName in CookieAuthenticationOptions as follow, after sign in, Request.IsAuthenticated in cshtml is set to **false** instead of expected **true**, and no cookie present:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn"),
            CookieDomain = ".azurewebsites.net"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ...
            });
    }
```

However once I removed the line CookieDomain=".azurewebsites.net", Request.IsAuthenticated is set to **true** automatically, there's cookie named **.AspNet.Cookies** present.

Is there any samples to change cookie domain name with Owin+OpenID